# How to pack all files needed for android emulator?

Tags: android, android-source

We have built aosp with our components, then try to pack all the files needed for running the emulator. The way we run the emulator is to do  `emulator -verbost -no-window -no-audio -shell -no-snapshot -no-snapstorage -port 5541 -writable-system -selinux disabled -qemu -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hn0,mac=52:55:00:d0:55:50 -netdevtap,id=hn0,ifname=ara_tap2,script=no,downscript=no`

Based on the output of `lunch my_target`, I checked the out/target/product/my_target folder, I removed some of the files under this my_target folder, the emulator still started.
So my question is what files under this my_target folder are the required files for the emulator to run (I guess some of them are not required based on my experiment), how to find/locate all of the files?

The build of aosp and running the emulator occur inside an android docker container.

Thanks for any ideas.